# Should I report loss on the last batch or the entire training dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

In the training loop below, you can see that `train_loss` represents the loss on the most recent batch.

Whereas the `eval_loss` is computed on the entire training dataset.

When I print it out, should I be recalculating the `train_loss` against the entire training split instead of the last batch?

```py
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Loop over batches.
    for i, batch in enumerate(samples_train['features']):
        
        train_preds = model(samples_train['features'][i])
        train_loss = loss_fn(train_preds, samples_train['labels'][i])

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
    # Only the training data is batched.
    eval_preds = model(samples_evaluate['features'])
    eval_loss = loss_fn(eval_preds, samples_evaluate['labels'])
    
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, Train_Loss: {float(train_loss)},  Eval_Loss: {float(eval_loss)}")
```

Comment: hmm now i am thinking about undersized batches and leaning toward the whole split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The losses should be calculated over the whole epoch (i.e. the whole dataset) instead of just the single batch. To implement this you could have a running count which adds up the losses of the individual batches and divides it by the number of batches after the epoch ends.

Comment: Nice yeah that would be much more efficient than loading the whole dataset again.